# invalid character are printed in program

Tags: c, struct

I have written the program

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student
{
    char name[22];
    char rollno[10];
    unsigned long long int phno;

};
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    char c[1];
    struct student cse[10],*p;
    p=cse;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
            printf("enter student name\n");
            gets(cse[i].name);
            printf("enter student roll number \n");
            gets(cse[i].rollno);
            printf("enter student phone number \n");
            scanf("%llu",&cse[i].phno);
            gets(c); //to catch the '\n' left unprocessed by scanf
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++);
    printf("the following is the information about CSE B student\n");
    printf("%-6s%-24s%-14s%-14s \n","S.no","student Name","Roll no","phone no.");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
            printf("%-6d%-24s%-20s%-14llu \n",i+1,(*p).name,(*p).rollno,(*p).phno);
            ++p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
the following is the information about CSE B student
S.no  student Name            Roll no       phone no.      
1     kapil                   1234567890��I      1234567890     
2     kumar                   9876543210��L     9876543210     
3     sharma                  5123467890��a1     5123467980
```

there are some unwanted and ununderstandable characters in the Roll no coloumns ,what is the cause of printing of those invalid characters

~

Comment: you have to use p->phno not (*p).phno....and similar stories

Comment: @ha9u63ar That's not true, they're identical. `->` is better style, but not different such that you __have__ to use it.

Comment: `gets()` – NOOOOOOOO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array `rollno` has storage only for 10 chars but you are inputting 10 or more chars. If your roll numbers are 10 digits, you need at least 11 chars to print it as string, one extra for the terminating null-byte. This is technically *[undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*, making your program invalid.

Note that `gets()` has been deprecated since C11 and you should really be using `fgets()` instead.